# Bootstrap Youtube Modal's button not working on testing with runtime errors which iam failed to fix

Tags: jquery, html, css, youtube, bootstrap-modal

so i have just completed my script with [Bootstrap Youtube Modal](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Autoplay-Youtube-Videos-In-Bootstrap-Modal-jQuery-YoutubeModal.html) Successfully but i have on testing it iam using the button example `<button class="yt-video" rel="some YT"><img .....=""/></button>` it doesn't work (once i click on the image/button to show the bootstrap model with the modal it doesn't do anything please some help)

Test URL: https://www.br-gaming.ga/dev-test/?p=1.0#screenshots (its first image/button which contains bandicam's copyright on the header of it)
Here is my Code:

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".yt-video").YouTubeModal({width: 500, height: 350})
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://www.br-gaming.ga/dev-test/js/bootstrap.youtubemodal.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                        <center>
         <button class="yt-video" rel="jSpQCX-ezG8"><img src="https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/jSpQCX-ezG8/maxresdefault.jpg" style="width: 800px;" /></button>           
                        </center>
```

i know that there are some kind of Runtime errors showed below but i tried fixing them multiple times with multiple methods but iam failed and its working successfull 100% on the demo of this JS Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

**Demo:** https://output.jsbin.com/sozocudobo

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>BootstrapYoutubeModal</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Autoplay-Youtube-Videos-In-Bootstrap-Modal-jQuery-YoutubeModal/bootstrap.youtubemodal.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<center>
<button class="yt-video" rel="jSpQCX-ezG8"><img src="https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/jSpQCX-ezG8/maxresdefault.jpg" style="width: 800px;" /></button>           
</center>  

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".yt-video").YouTubeModal({width: 500, height: 350})
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks your code worked for me at the demo but not on my Website: https://www.br-gaming.ga/dev-test/?p=1.0 - Note: i have edited line number 111 on Bootstrap Youtube Modal.js to fill my needs: it was ```return ['<iframe  title="YouTube video player" width="', width, '" height="', height, '" ',``` and i replace it with ```return ['<iframe id="ytvideo" title="YouTube video player" width="', width, '" height="', height, '" ',``` added a ```id="..."``` for some reasons but it doesn't work for me after this edit .